# Where can I find existing Service Principals for the business units?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-service-principal

changed teams, looking for names of service principals. only found example for Ent.Capabilities
https://azure-help-ui.prd.cdc2.cfapps.8451.com/content/automation-tools/databricks-jobs.htm?Highlight=service%20principal#principal

Comment: I think you have pasted your environment databricks URL which is not recommended . Please share as Screenshot .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.